# substring to trim US 5+4 postal codes but keep Canada zip codes untouched

Tags: java, substring

I'm in the need of writing a logic for a middleware java based solution to be able to trim a 5+4 digit US postal code and return(trim/substring) only the 5 digit code. But... I need to have the code to not modify any Canadian zip codes too (ABCD DEF).

How to I achieve this using a software that uses Java version 7.5?

Comment: Are you certain you need to trim this? The ZIP+4 is actually very good if you need to mail something to someone. Anyway, use a regex like `(\\d{5})-\\d{4}` if it matches that it's 5 digits followed by a dash then 4 digits (and you can get `group(1)`).

Comment: Thank you. I'm aware that the zip+4 brings value, however for a business reason it is not possible to use it. But thanks I'm going to use this suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

If the code has more than 8 characters, trim the last 5 characters. That's pretty much it.

Comment: Thanks!. Yes I'm actually using substring with a 0 start position and trim the last 7 values. For Canada is working, but for US it adds two zeroes... that's the simple fix I'm trying to sell. having an extra zero shouldn't be a problem :D

Answer (score 0):

You could use a web service to validate your postal codes. [Here](https://hd1-units.herokuapp.com/zip?code=12180") is one such service, example is for the zipcode "12180" in the United States. It will return status code 417, for "Expectation Failed" if it's an invalid US zipcode. Hope that helps.

Comment: This is coole. I'll check in to ways to look for that option. The middleware solution has already a mapping with data skeloton and is not able to call for a WS to validate it, however I can use a Value Table to read the format if it's true or false depending on the format needed...